# JavaScript: How to efficiently retrieve array object item to a certain property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given this array object:

```
[{eventTitle=Event title 1, eventId=xyz1@google.com, startDate=Sun Mar 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, endDate=Mon Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018},
 {eventTitle=Event title 2, eventId=xyz2@google.com, startDate=Tue Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019, endDate=Wed Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019},
 {eventTitle=Event title 3, eventId=xyz3@google.com, startDate=Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020, endDate=Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020},
 .
 .
 .]
```

How to efficiently retrieve the corresponding `startDate` to a certain `eventTitle` without looping/searching through the array? For example, I have `Event title 2` and want to get `Tue Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019`.

**EDIT:**

The array object is sorted by `startDate`.

Comment: You can create a map with `eventTitle` as key and entire object as value. The all you need to do is `map[ searchTitle ].startDate`

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a binary search on your array. Provided your array is sorted. -> `O(log(n))`

```
[obj1,obj2,obj3....obj100]
```

test the object in the middle `(obj50)`, then decide if you have to
search in the half `[obj1...obj49]` or in the half `[obj51...obj100]`

Otherwise you can pass your objects (Events) into an other data structure like a tree. -> `O(log(n))`
Just looping through your whole array wouldn't be efficient, but if you don't repeat it with too many its would be fine as well. But sorting your array from the beginning would be the best solution.

Edit:
The following code shows a basic example of an binary search implementation.

```js
const events = [{
    eventTitle: "Event title 1",
    eventId: "xyz1@google.com",
    startDate: "Sun Mar 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018",
    endDate: "Mon Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018"
  },
  {
    eventTitle: "Event title 2",
    eventId: "xyz2@google.com",
    startDate: "Tue Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019",
    endDate: "Wed Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019"
  },
  {
    eventTitle: "Event title 3",
    eventId: "xyz3@google.com",
    startDate: "Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    endDate: "Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"
  },
  {
    eventTitle: "Event title 4",
    eventId: "xyz4@google.com",
    startDate: "Fri Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2021",
    endDate: "Sat Mar 22 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2021"
  },
  {
    eventTitle: "Event title 5",
    eventId: "xyz5@google.com",
    startDate: "Fri Mar 22 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2022",
    endDate: "Sat Mar 23 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2022"
  }
];

function binarySearch(array, value, borderLeft, borderRight) {
  if (borderLeft <= borderRight) {
    var index = Math.floor((borderLeft + borderRight) / 2);
    var number = getNumberFromTitle(array[index].eventTitle);
    if (number == value) {
      return array[index].startDate;
    } else if (number > value) {
      return binarySearch(array, value, borderLeft, index - 1);
    } else {
      return binarySearch(array, value, index + 1, borderRight);
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function getNumberFromTitle(title) {
  var tmp = title.split(" ");
  return tmp[tmp.length - 1];
}

console.log(binarySearch(events, 4, 0, events.length - 1));
```

Comment: Assuming it's sorted... The OP doesn't promise that. :-)

Comment: The array object is sorted.

Comment: Then a binary search is another viable option.

Comment: @Luca Jung Could you add a live example?

Comment: @Ben sure! Added it to my answer.

Comment: @Luca Jung Thank you very much! The array object is sorted by `startDate`. So if I need to retrieve only one `startDate` or a few `startDates` to its/their corresponding `eventTitle`/`eventTitles` binary seach is the way to go but if I need to retrieve every single `startDate` to its corresponding `eventTitle` anyway I should go for the Map solution?

Comment: @Ben yes i think so. My solution is working fine when the array is sorted by the event. Otherwise I would go for the map.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "by the event"?

Comment: @Ben The first object in the array is event title 1, the second is event title 2 and so on. At time you posted your question it wasn't clear, that the array is sorted by start date.

Comment: @Luca Jung So you meant the `eventTitle`. Could you add another live example for the array sorted by `startDate`?

Answer (score 1):

If you **only** have the array, you have no option but to search through it.

But if you're going to have to search it more than once, you can make a single pass through it to produce a Map, so that subsequent searches are sublinear (faster than searching through the array with a loop). You'd do that like this:

```
const map = new Map(theArray.map(entry => [entry.eventTitle, entry.startDate]));
```

Then getting by title is:

```
const startDate = map.get("some title");
```

Live Example:

```js
const theArray = [
    {eventTitle: "Event title 1", eventId: "xyz1@google.com", startDate: "Sun Mar 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018", endDate: "Mon Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018"},
    {eventTitle: "Event title 2", eventId: "xyz2@google.com", startDate: "Tue Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019", endDate: "Wed Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019"},
    {eventTitle: "Event title 3", eventId: "xyz3@google.com", startDate: "Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020", endDate: "Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"},
];
// Building it:
const map = new Map(theArray.map(entry => [entry.eventTitle, entry.startDate]));
// Using it:
console.log(map.get("Event title 2"));       // "Tue Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019"
console.log(map.get("Event title 3"));       // "Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"
console.log(map.get("no such event title")); // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(You can do the same thing with an object instead of a Map (just be sure to create it with `Object.create(null)` so it doesn't have a prototype), but Map is specifically designed for this.)

---

Note that this example assumes there's only one event for each title. If there may be more than one, you need to build the map differently so that it points you to an array of only entries for that title.

Comment: What do you mean by "only have the array"? What else could I have? Your example returns the whole object but not only the date.

Comment: @Ben - *"What else could I have?"* A Map like the one in the answer. The point is that if you don't have something like that, scanning each time or building something like that are your only options. (Except now you've said it's sorted, you can do a binary search as [Luca points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60790784/157247).) Didn't realize you just wanted the date, that's a trivial change to the above.

Comment: The array object is sorted by `startDate`. So if I need to retrieve only one `startDate` or a few `startDates` to its/their corresponding `eventTitle`/`eventTitles` binary seach is the way to go but if I need to retrieve every single `startDate` to its corresponding `eventTitle` anyway I should go for the Map solution?

Comment: @Ben - Not necessarily *all* of them, but if you have several you need to look up, you may be better off with a Map than repeated binary searches; for only a few, doing a binary search for each of them may be the way to go. Or if efficiency is really, really important, you may want to investigate multiple approaches and pick the one that gives you the best results in your real scenario. In that case, I'd consider at least three: 1. Building a Map from the array and then using it for lookups. 2. Doing binary searches. 3. Skipping the array and making the Map your starting point. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Hm, how to skip the array?

Comment: @Ben - It depends where and how you get the data.You may not be able to. But for instance, if the data comes from a database and you can get it formatted in `[ [eventTitle, startDate], [eventType, startDate], [eventTitle, startDate] ]` form instead, that goes straight into a Map constructor. But yeah, the more I think about it, you're probably going to have an array starting point regardless. Either that or a lot of `map.set("title", "start date")` calls, which is unlikely to be efficient. :-)

Comment: The data come from _Google Calendar_ via _Google Apps Script_.

Answer (score 1):

**You can create mapper util. First, it will loop once, `O(n)`. Later all call will be `O(1)`**

I have working code:

https://gist.github.com/deepakshrma/4b6a0a31b4582d6418ec4f76b7439781

```js
function Mapper(array , key){
    this.map = array.reduce(function(map, item){
        var val = item[key];
        if(!map[val]){
            map[val] = [];
        }
        map[val].push(item);
        return map;
    },{});
}
Mapper.FIRST_INDEX = 0;
Mapper.prototype.find = function find(key){
    return this.map[key] && this.map[key][Mapper.FIRST_INDEX]//return blank array
};
Mapper.prototype.findAll = function find(key, returnUndefined){
    return this.map[key] && this.map[key] || (returnUndefined? undefined: []);//return blank array
};
var users = [{eventTitle:"Event title 1", eventId:"xyz1@google.com", startDate:"Sun Mar 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018", endDate:"Mon Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018"},
 {eventTitle:"Event title 2", eventId:"xyz2@google.com", startDate:"Tue Mar 19 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019", endDate:"Wed Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019"},
 {eventTitle:"Event title 3", eventId:"xyz3@google.com", startDate:"Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020", endDate:"Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"}];
//How to use

var userMapper = new Mapper(users , 'eventTitle');
console.log(userMapper.find("Event title 2")); 
var userToFind = ["Event title 3", "Event title 2"];
var reqUsers =  userToFind.map(function(name){
    return userMapper.find(name);
});
console.log(reqUsers);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!